# Xcode 5 NSAttributedString in UIButton

Tags: ios, xcode, nsattributedstring

I using newest Xcode and iOS7.
I am trying to set nsattributed string on UIButton without luck. It shows correctly in the preview, but it doesn't apply changes to the actual button (look at the intro button in the image below)... Kind of frustrating.

How can I force Xcode to apply nsattributed text? 
[image]

Comment: What image and why is Xcode in the title?

Comment: Because I am using Xcode 5 IB to alter text.
I added screenshot of the problem to my post.

Comment: No image; just a busy icon for me.

Comment: http://www.flickr.com/photos/104552419@N03/